# Problems getting OpenLDAP memberOf working

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm not very familiar with OpenLDAP, but I'm trying to get a local instance working in order to test a client in development, which needs the memberOf attribute.

I've downloaded and installed OpenLDAP on a Centos 7 VM, per the instructions at http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/guide.html#A Quick-Start Guide.  I did not use package management to install it.  Since I'm using 2.4.45, it's using the cn=config OLC config and not the slapd.conf configuration scheme

At step 4 above, I used the --enable-memberof and --enable-refint flag to the configure script.  When I ran the pre-install tests, it did run the memberof tests, and they passed, so I know the overlay can be applied somehow.

I've tried the directions found at https://adimian.com/blog/2014/10/how-to-enable-memberof-using-openldap/ and, with slight variants, many other places.  I've run into the following issues with this...

1. Errors about an invalid objectClass oldModuleList during ldapadd
2. Insufficient access errors during ldapadd
3. I don't have a local directory that corresponds to the module path found in any of the examples.  I don't seem to have the memberof.la file anywhere on the machine.

Is this even on the right track?  Or will the process be different because I installed from source or used the --enable-memberof flag?

Let me know if there's any info I need to provide.

Update:
Currently, I am trying to add the entry with dn `dn: olcOverlay={0}memberof,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config` as found in the linked instructions above.  I get 
`# ldapadd -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=aaron,dc=com" -W -f member.ldif
Enter LDAP Password: 
adding new entry "olcOverlay={0}memberof,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config"
ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)`

Another update:
Progress!

I added an olcRootPW to the cn=config database by editing
`etc/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={0}config.ldif`
then used that dn to run the ldapadd:
`ldapadd -x -D "cn=config" -W -f member.ldif`
I had to put the {0} and {1} back.

Trying to add the first refint ldif failed, but I *think* I don't need that since these aren't modules, but compiled directly into slapd based on how I configured it.

Now I'm trying to add the second refint entry and getting

```
[root@openldap openldap]# ldapadd -x -D "cn=config" -W -f refint2.ldif 
Enter LDAP Password: 
adding new entry "olcOverlay={1}refint,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config"
ldap_add: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
    additional info: olcRefintAttribute <manager>: attribute type undefined
```

Comment: You need to provide the actual commands and the actual errors they cause.

Comment: Well 'insufficient access' is self-explanatory, surely? Don't put code in comments, and don't put things in comments that should be part of your question. I can't read that and neither can you.

Comment: But I am using the root user and credentials the system was set up with.  I've found a few things online about this but they only reference the slapd.conf style of config.  I haven't found any info on how to resolve this with the cn=config style.

Comment: You should not provide the `{0}` and `{1}`. OpenLDAP adds the sequence numbers automatically

Comment: Removed them, no difference.

Comment: Try it removing the `{0}` and retaining the `{1}`. You shouldn't use the rootDN for anything: that's for the server. You should define an administrative user for this purpose and give him the appropriate permissions. The primary reference is the [OpenLDAP site](http://www.openldap.org), and the only secondary reference you can really trust is the [Zytrax guide](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's everything I had to do to get it working from my original issue:

Add an olcRootPW entry to the olcDatabase={0}config.ldif config entry.  As EJP says, this is bad form, but since this is a local testing directory only, and I only want it to allow me to test a client...

Without the {0} and {1} items in the file, the load still failed.  I but both back and it worked.  I did not go back to check EJP's suggestion to only have the {1}.

Then the ldapadd command needs to be run with bind dn 'cn=config'.  At that point the entry to enable the memberof config would add successfully.

I tried to add the first refint file, the one that does the module.  This did not work, I got an error about the olcModuleList attribute.  I think since I compiled the overlays directly into OpenLDAP via the --enable-memberof and --enable-refint I didn't need this part?

For the second refint file, the one to add the overlay, I just needed to remove the 'manager owner' part of the attributes, since my directory does not have those attributes.  At this point the ldif added successfully.

Then I went into the directory and added users, groups, and assigned users to groups, and (once I told it to fetch the operational attributes) lo and behold my users had the appropriate memberOf attributes!